# Using StreamReader in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, streamreader

I found a very annyoing problem, and I given up to find the answer on my own. I'm currently working on a **Windows 8 Store application**, and I am using MS Visual Studio 2012 (of course).

I wanted to read a csv file when my application is starting. I have created a new .cs file, with classes, and one of them should own this file reading method. At this point is everyting all right, but when I started to implement the reader, I have got the following error message:

> The best overloaded method match for System.IO.StreamReader.StreamReader(System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid argument.
>   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.Stream'

I was wondering, because all the MS references says that the `System.IO.StreamReader` can have a string as parameter. Weird. Just for fun, I created a simple Console Application, and I copied all these StreamReader stuff, and what's a miracle, it was working correctly...

Maybe I know too few about Win 8 Store application, but I honestly could not find any information about this problem.

The code from store application:

```
public void readCSV()
{
    string path = @"ms-appdata://Asstes/Content/data.csv";
    try
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = newSystem.IO.StreamReader(path)) 
        {

            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {

    }

}
```

And the code which was accepted by the compiler (as a console application):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    System.IO.StreamReader reader;
    reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("path.csv");
    reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Oh, so I knew few about this... okay, thank you. But this question is a bit more specific than the other one.

Comment: Hm, the linked answer's soulution is no longer available as I see...

Comment: I added a comment on the answer that contains a new link.

Comment: Thank you!
I found some MS example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj155757.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to read resource files:

```
    public static async Task<IList<Person>> GetPeople()
    {
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/People.xml"));
        var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
                var a = sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
     }
```

People.xml has a build action of Content/Do not copy.